# signal: segmentation fault (core dumped) || Discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js, segmentation-fault

I have this error and am not sure how to fix it. Any ideas?

I am not sure how to fix this. This is for a Discord bot on my server and the code works for a different bot (i did the exact same code there) but not this one. I am not entirely sure what the error means. (I have only been coding for a few months)

signal: segmentation fault (core dumped)

P.S I am using replit and uptime to host it.

````
    "GUILDS",
    "GUILD_MESSAGES"   ] });

const config = process.env; bot.on('ready', () => {   console.log(bot.user.username + ' is online.') }); //CONSTANT COMMANDS



//Text Commands

bot.on('messageCreate', (msg) => {   if(msg.author.bot || msg.channel.type === "dm")   return;   const messageArray = msg.content.split(' ');   const cmd = messageArray[0];   const args = msg.content.substring(msg.content.indexOf(' ') + 1);   const prefix = config.prefix;

if(cmd.toLowerCase() === prefix + 'discord' ) { msg.channel.send({   content: 'link' }) } });

bot.on('messageCreate', (msg) => {   if(msg.author.bot || msg.channel.type === "dm")   return;   const messageArray = msg.content.split(' ');   const cmd = messageArray[0];   const args = msg.content.substring(msg.content.indexOf(' ') + 1);   const prefix = config.prefix;

if(cmd.toLowerCase() === prefix + 'realm' ) { msg.channel.send({   content: 'link' }) } });

bot.on('messageCreate', message => {   if(message.content.toLowerCase() === prefix + "help") {   let embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("Command List")
    .setDescription("**?Player Description**- Shows a description of all the players. \n **realm**- Sends a realm invite \n **?factions**- Shows the factions of this season and their members \n **?info {faction}**- Shows the lore and banner of a faction \n **?help**- Shows this help menu \n **?quote**- Sends a random quote from the server \n **?world**- sends the world lore.")
    .setColor("RANDOM")
    message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed]})   } });

bot.on('messageCreate', message => {   if(message.content.toLowerCase() === prefix + "world") {   let embed2
= new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("World Lore")
    .setDescription("realm lore")
    .setColor("RANDOM")
    message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed2]})   } });


bot.on('messageCreate', message => {   if(message.content.toLowerCase() === prefix + "info giraduan") {   let embed2 = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("The Giraduan Dominion")
    .setDescription("faction1 info")
    .setColor("RANDOM")
    message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed2]})   } });

bot.on('messageCreate', message => {   if(message.content.toLowerCase() === prefix + "info rpa") {   let embed2 = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("Rerualin Preservation Association")
    .setDescription("faction2 info")
    .setColor("RANDOM"
    )
    message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed2]})   } });

bot.on('messageCreate', message => {   if(message.content.toLowerCase() === prefix + "player description") {  let embed2 = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("Player descriptions")
    .setDescription("description of players")
    .setColor("RANDOM")
    message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed2]})   } });



bot.on('messageCreate', message => {   if(message.content.toLowerCase() === prefix + "character example") {   let embed2 = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("Example Character")
    .setDescription("**Name:** Cinaxx \n **Gender:** He/him/his \n **Class:** Twilight Mage \n **Race:** Halfing Dark Elf \n \n **Bio:** \n ㅤㅤDescription for character"}
    .setThumbnail('https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/877727121341026304/904443409614401546/YIN_YANG-removebg-preview.png')
    message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed2]})   } });

bot.login(config.token);```
````

Comment: You should not have multiple **messageCreate** events. All of your logic should be handled inside one event. This could be (and is probably already) causing memory leaks which is a plausible explanation for the error message you're getting. Reduce each of your events down to only be inside a single event listener

Comment: Any reason why you have multiple listeners for `messageCreate`? You only need **one** listener per event in order to avoid bugs.

Comment: @Elitezen After changing it to this [https://pastebin.com/9UzPMdeA]
It still does not seem to be working.

I am getting the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: To use the link remove the ]
Accidently forgot a space